# Move CSS Border to Right on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to animate the moving of the outline/border of the first link to the right to be over the second link to the right when you click on the second link, and the same for third link, etc.

```
<span style="font-size:9px;text-transform:uppercase;">
  <span style="border: 1px #000 solid;border-radius: 3px;padding: 5px;margin-right: 9px;">Link 1</span>    
  <span style="color:#32CD32">Link 2</span>    
  <span style="color:#32CD32">Link 3</span>    
  <span style="color:#32CD32">Link 4</span>
</span>
```

This is the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/k7pp7/

Was curious how you would do this.

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. You have none...

Comment: You want to animate it? I think you need to use an extra HTML element that has the border etc. and animate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't need animation and you only need to highlight the active link:

1. spans are not links. anchors are.
2. create a class for active state and assign that class on click.

*Quick sample*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/k7pp7/26/

*Quick Js*:

```
$('a').on("click", function() {
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

---

If you want animation, then:

1. wrap the links in a wrapper and have an extra element with absolute positioning.
2. onclick, get the position of the link and position the extra element there.

*Quick sample*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4xafT/1/

*Quick Js*:

```
$('a').on("click", function() {
    var $active = $('.active'),
        pos = $(this).position();

    $active.show().animate({
        'top': pos.top, 
        'left': pos.left,
        'width': $(this).width() + 8
    }, 500);
})
```

;

Comment: This is perfect thanks a lot. How would I get it so the border starts being over the first link? rather than just appearing when i click on an item.

Comment: @user1982011: that's simple. fire a click on the first anchor in domready after you have bound the click event. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4xafT/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list and do something like this :

```
    $('#yourULID > li').click(function(){
    $(this).css({"border": "","border-radius": "","padding": "","margin-right":"","color":"#32CD32"});
    $(this).next().css({"border": "1px #000 solid","border-radius": "3px","padding": "5px","margin-right":"9px"});
    });
```